# Cron is not firing on specific schedule

Tags: node.js, cron

I want to run a cron job on a specific date of every month in node js.I am using a npm module named 'Cron' but the function is not firing on the specific date.Here is the code I am using

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
 new CronJob('0 0 0 21 * *', function () {
    // this code run will on the 21st of every month
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: You have one too many leading zero's.

Answer (score 0):

Your cron pattern seems right but you can also try removing first **0** , beacuse second is not important in your case .I think problem is about your timezone value. Probably, your timezone is not `America/Los_Angeles` try to change it.

To fin your current timezone value check this site : http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: It is working fine when I specify hour and minute.And that fulfills my need as I just wanted to run the job at any time on 21st. Thanks